# Error when trying to run a Selenium test with PHPUnit

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I wanted to run a Selenium test with PHPUnit but this error appeared and I have no idea what it tries to tell me:

> $ phpunit ApplicationTest/Controller/StationTest.php
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Config\Exception\RuntimeException' with                                                                                                                                                            message 'Filename "" cannot be found relative to the working directory' in
>   C:\Users*****\Documents*****\******\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Config\Factory.php:73

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: It is in error reposne `'Filename "" cannot be found relative to the working directory' in` means somewhere in your code you are referencing file "Filename" which doesnt exist

Comment: as @dafyk already pointed out that might be the cause but you need to share your StationTest code if you want more helpful responses

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown from [Zend\Config\Factory::fromFile()](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-config/blob/master/src/Factory.php#L73-L76) if it's called with a parameter that is no valid file path. In your case, the parameter is empty (`''`)

It looks like you have a Zend Framework application that needs some configuration file which is not provided.

To debug this error, take a look at the exception stack trace to see where this code is called. One way to get the stack trace is to wrap your test case in a `try...catch` block like this:

```
function testSomething()
{
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getTraceAsString(); // alternatively, write to log file
    }
}
```